# Accessing style attribute individually

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack` in c#. I created a div element with some attribute like,

```
HtmlNode div = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>");
div.Attributes.Add("style","width:100px;height:100px;color:red;position:absolute;");
```

Now I want to know that is there any method in HtmlAgilityPack by with i can access the style Attributes individually, like we do in jQuery  :

```
         $("div").width(); or $("div").css("width");
```

Comment: Short anser: no. You can use GetAttributeValue to pull the style, but you'd have to parse the individual properties yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/csquery), which is in fact like jQuery:

```
CQ div = CQ.Create("<div></div>");

div.CssSet( new {
    width="100px",
    height="100px",
    color="red",
    position="absolute"
});

//.. or

div.Css("width","100px").Css( ... ) ...

string width = div.Css("width");       // width=="100px"

int widthInt = div.Css<int>("width");  // widthInt==100
```

It implements every DOM manipulation method of jQuery, so the API should be very familiar. It also provides an implemention that mostly mimics the browser DOM, e.g.

```
var nodeName = div[0].NodeName;         // nodeName=="DIV";

div[0].AppendChild(div.Document.CeateElement("span"));   // add a span child
```

There are a couple exceptions, `CssSet` is one of them, where the overloaded methods in javascript didn't work out in C# so a different method had to be used. (The other one is `AttrSet` when setting from an object). It's also got extensive unit test coverage, including much of the test suite from jQuery ported to C#, and selectors are much faster than HTML Agility Pack (not to mention a lot less confusing since they're just CSS) thanks to a subselect-capable index.